# css in django templates

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a problem using css in my django template,

In my `settings.py` i have this :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/')
STATIC_URL = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
```

In my paths I have the folder `"static/css/home_css.css"`

In my template home.html I have the link tag :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/home_css.css" media="all" />
```

but it doens't work in order to render de css.
If anybody knows what happens please

Comment: why does your path have .css file?

Comment: it is just my folder where my css is"static/css/home_css.css"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I put my directory static into aplication root path, and set 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`STATIC_URL` shouldn't point to the path in the filesystem. `STATIC_ROOT` should.

```
import os

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `settings.py` add `'django.core.context_processors.static',` at `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` like in this example:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

**EDIT**

And if you're working with the local dev-server you'll need something like this in your `urls.py`:

`(r'static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '%s' % os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'static')}),`

Comment: do you work with developement-server or production (e.g. apache)? What is shown when you type the URL to the CSS into your browser? Do you get a 404-Error?